# how to insert to table with JTA?

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, jta

I wanna to persist data to table. When I call the save method, it throws an exception: "**EXCEPTION saveToDB ---java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction is not accessible when using JTA with JPA-compliant transaction access enabled**"

I've tried to use the following snippet to fix the issue, with no success:

```
@Resource
private UserTransaction transaction;
public method() {
  try {
     transaction.begin();
     ...do some persistence...
     transaction.commit();
  } catch (Exception e) {
     transaction.rollback();
  }
}
```

How to avoid the given exception when persisting the entity?

This is my save method:

```
private void saveReportToDB(String id, String name, String data,String mode) {
        try {
            logger.info("--- START saveToDB ---");

            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            Template report = new Template();
            report.setId(id);
            report.setName(name);
            report.setStatus(ReportStatus.ACTIVE);
            report.setTemplateContent(data);//throws Exception
            report.setTemplateDscx(name);
            report.setTplCode(mode);
            report.setCommitId(id);

            entityManager.persist(report);
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

        }catch (Exception ex){
            logger.info("--- EXEPTON saveToDB ---"+ex);
        }

    }
```

And this is my entity (partially):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEMPLATES")
public class Template {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;
    @Column(name = "name", length = 128)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "code", length = 24, unique = true)
    private String code;
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "content")
    private String content;

    @Column(name = "dscx")
    private String dscx;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a container managed transaction - as it appears to be the case -, there is no reason to inject an UserTransaction object or in using entityManager#getTransaction() methods. You should only execute the method inside a CDI @Transactional annotated method or an EJB @TransactionAttribute annotated method.

In short: you just need to remove your transaction calls inside your saveReportToDB method and let CDI or EJB transaction control solve the problem for you.

If you really need to control transaction, you must annotate your bean so the transaction control is bean controlled (instead of container controlled), so you will be able to use the injected UserTransaction.